# Need to call InsertBulk<T>(IEnumerable<T> pocos) but T only known at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, petapoco, dynamictype, npoco

NPoco (a .NET micro ORM, derived from PetaPoco) has a method for bulk-inserting records into a database, given a list of a generic type. The method signature is:

```
void InsertBulk<T>(IEnumerable<T> pocos);
```

Internally it takes the name of the type T and uses it to determine the DB table to insert into (similarly the type's property names are mapped to the column names). *Therefore it is critically important that a variable of the correct type is passed to the method*.

My challenge is this:

- I am given a list of objects to insert into the DB, as `List<IDataItem>` where IDataItem is an interface that all insertable objects' classes must implement
- The list may contain objects of any type that implements IDataItem, and there may be a mixture of types in the list
- *To underline the problem - I do not know at compile time the actual concrete type that I have to pass to InsertBulk*

I have tried the following approach, but the result of Convert.ChangeType is Object, so I am passing a list of Objects to InsertBulk, which is invalid.

```
   private static Exception SaveDataItemsToDatabase(List<IDataItem> dtos)
   {
        using (var db = new DbConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                var dtosByType = dtos.GroupBy(x => x.GetType());

                db.Data.BeginTransaction();

                foreach (var dataType in dtosByType)
                {
                    var type = dataType.Key;
                    var dtosOfType = dataType.Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, type));

                    db.Data.InsertBulk(dtosOfType);
                }

                db.Data.CommitTransaction();

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                db.Data.RollbackTransaction();

                return ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried using `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: If I declare dtosOfType as dynamic, I get the same result - the variable passed to BulkInsert is a list of Object.

Comment: Did you try using Reflection? Use `Type.GetMethod()` to get the method defintion and then use `MethodInfo.Invoke()` it with the respective `System.Type`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new list of type `List<T>` and copy all your items to it, then call `InsertBulk` via reflection.

```
foreach(var g in groups)
{

    var dataItemType = g.Key;
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { dataItemType });
    var list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

    foreach(var data in g)
        list.Add(data);

    db.Data.GetType()
           .GetMethod("InsertBulk")
           .MakeGenericMethod(dataItemType)
           .Invoke(db.Data, new object[] { list });

}
```

See it working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BS2FLy

Comment: Getting ex on this line: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestConsole.Program+IDataItem]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Program+Test1Dto]'.

Comment: Yes It works! Thanks so much - thought I had hit an impossible problem!

Comment: @Laurence no such thing :P

Comment: @Laurence Oh and you might wanna refactor this part out of the loop to lessen the impact on performance: `db.Data.GetType().GetMethod("InsertBulk")`

Comment: OK yes - makes sense

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you to do what you want (though a bit hacky).

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var items = new IDataItem[] {
            new TestItem(),
            new TestItem(),
            new TestItem2(),
            new TestItem2(),
        };

        foreach (var kv in items.GroupBy(c => c.GetType())) {
            // group by actual type
            var type = kv.Key;
            var batch = kv.ToArray();
            // grab BulkInsert<Type> method
            var insert = typeof(Test).GetMethod("BulkInsert").MakeGenericMethod(type);
            // create array of Type[]
            var casted = Array.CreateInstance(type, batch.Length);
            Array.Copy(batch, casted, batch.Length);
            // invoke
            insert.Invoke(new Test(), new object[] { casted});
        }            

        Console.ReadKey();
    }        
}

public interface IDataItem {

}

public class TestItem : IDataItem {

}

public class TestItem2 : IDataItem
{

}

public class Test {
    public void BulkInsert<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

If use your original code, it will be something like:

```
    private static Exception SaveDataItemsToDatabase(List<IDataItem> dtos)
    {
        using (var db = new DbConnection())
        {
            try
            {                    
                db.Data.BeginTransaction();
                foreach (var dataType in dtos.GroupBy(x => x.GetType())) {
                    var type = dataType.Key;
                    var items = dataType.ToArray();
                    var insert = db.Data.GetType().GetMethod("BulkInsert").MakeGenericMethod(type);
                    // create array of Type[]
                    var casted = Array.CreateInstance(type, items.Length);
                    Array.Copy(items, casted, items.Length);
                    // invoke
                    insert.Invoke(db.Data, new object[] {casted});
                }

                db.Data.CommitTransaction();

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                db.Data.RollbackTransaction();

                return ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer than dcastro.

Comment: When I was writing it - his answer was deleted. Plus, his answer won't actually work - he needs to cast array to correct type.

Comment: This also works ... very similar to dcastro, but he posted his a few mins before this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Laurence well actually this solution was posted about 25 minutes before dcastro posted his (correct) one :) But that does not matter much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
   private static Exception SaveDataItemsToDatabase(List<IDataItem> dtos)
   {
        using (var db = new DbConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                var dtosByType = dtos.GroupBy(x => x.GetType());

                db.Data.BeginTransaction();
                var method = db.Data.GetType().GetMethod("InsertBulk");
                foreach (var dataType in dtosByType)
                {
                    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(dataType.Key);
                    genericMethod.Invoke(db.Data, new object[] { dataType.Value };                   
                }

                db.Data.CommitTransaction();

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                db.Data.RollbackTransaction();

                return ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get this exception when Invoke called: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestConsole.Program+IDataItem]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestConsole.Program+Test1Dto]'.

Comment: Test1Dto is one of my types that implements IDataItem

Comment: try calling dataType.Value.ToList()

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take an educated guess on this one since I don't have the code to run it on my side.

How about:

```
private static Exception SaveDataItemsToDatabase(List<IDataItem> dtos)
{
    using (var db = new DbConnection())
    {
        try
        {

            db.Data.BeginTransaction();

            dtos
                .GroupBy(dto => dto.GetType())
                .ForEach(grp => {
                    db.Data.BulkInsert(dtos.Where(n => n.GetType().Equals(grp.Key).ToList());
                });

            db.Data.CommitTransaction();

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            db.Data.RollbackTransaction();

            return ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting same kind of error as before ("Cannot access destination table 'IDataItem'.") .... because BulkInsert called with variable of type List of IDataItem.